# How to find the first occurrence within a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

So basically, I am simply trying to search for a string within a string.

Although, it is a little trickier than that.

I have three small strings, `one`, `two`, `three`

And I have one large string, which is saved as a variable and is quite long.. A few paragraphs long actually.

I need to create a function that allows me to see which string occurs first.

For example, a string like this:

```
Hello, testing testing one test some more two
```

Will return `one` since it occurred before `two`.

Another example:

```
Test a paragraph three and testing some more one test test two
```

Will return `three` since it occurred before both `one` and `two`.

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples on how to do this? Very new to PHP and not to sure how to go about doing this. Thanks!

Comment: Use `stripos` on every "small string" and see which position is the minimum?

Comment: Do you want the position or just which string comes first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$string = 'Hello, testing testing one test some more two';
$words = Array("one", "two", "three");
$low_pos = strlen($string);
$first = '';
foreach($words as $word)
{
    $pos = strpos($string, $word);
    echo "Found ".$word." at ".$pos."<br />";
    if($pos !== false && $pos < $low_pos)
    {
        $low_pos = $pos;
        $first = $word;
    }
}

echo $string."<br />";
echo "FIRST: ".$first;
```

Output:

```
Found one at 23
Found two at 42
Found three at 
Hello, testing testing one test some more two
FIRST: one
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) with a simple alternation:

```
if (preg_match('/one|two|three/', $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

Results:

```
Hello, testing testing one test some more two
-> one

Test a paragraph three and testing some more one test test two
-> three
```

If you need the position as well, you can add a flag:

```
if (preg_match('/one|two|three/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    echo 'Found ' . $matches[0][0] . ' @ ' . $matches[0][1];
}
```

As a function:

```
function findFirst($string, array $needles)
{
    $pattern = '/' . join('|', array_map(function($str) {
        return preg_quote($str, '/');
    }, $needles)) . '/';

    if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) {
        return $matches[0];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use:

```
echo findFirst($string, array('one', 'two', 'three'));
```

Comment: Great answer, although I find having a function easier to read and modify. Will definitely use this next time round since it is far more simplistic. Thanks!

Comment: @fizzix I've updated my answer to include what a function would look like.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Simply something like

```
$longString = "Hello, testing testing one test some more two";
$onePosition = strpos($longString, "one");
$twoPosition = strpos($longString, "two");
$threePosition = strpos($longString, "three");

$onePosition; // 23
$twoPosition; // 42
$threePosition; // -1
```

Then you would just compare each variable to find the lowest. Clunky but for 3 variables not much work.

Comment: But wouldn't `$threePosition` be the lowest since it is `-1`?

Comment: You would check for > 0.

Comment: strpos() returns false if the needle is not found (not -1). You'd have to first check that each variable is not false, and then compare the ones that aren't against each other.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php

    $arrWords = array("one", "two", "three");
    $strInput = "Test a paragraph three and testing some more one test test two";

    function getFirstOccurrence($strInput, $arrWords) {
        $arrInput = explode(" ", $strInput);
        foreach($arrInput as $strInput) {
            if(in_array($strInput, $arrWords)) {
                return $strInput;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    print "First word is: " . getFirstOccurrence($strInput, $arrWords);

?>
```

Comment: Think your answer is probably the most reliable, especially with the implementation of the array search. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample algorithm:

```
function getFirstWord(array $needles, $haystack) {
    $best = null; //the best position
    $first = null; //the first word

    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        $pos = strpos($haystack, $needle);
        if($pos !== false) {
            if($best === null || $pos < $best) {
                $best = $pos;
                $first = $needle;
            }
        }
    }

    //returns the first word, or null if none of $needles found
    return $first;
}

$needles = array('one', 'two', 'three');
echo getFirstWord($needles, 'Hello, testing testing one test some more two'); // one
echo getFirstWord($needles, 'Test a paragraph three and testing some more one test test two'); // three
```

An optimal solution would minimise iterations over $haystack. You could start at the beginning of the string, and each time you advance a character, look for any of the $needles starting at the current position. As soon as you find one, bingo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy you can use a closure with array_map, array_filter, array_search and min.

```
function whichFirst(array $list, $string){
    // get a list of the positions of each word
    $positions = array_map(function($val) use ($string){
                                return strpos($string, $val);
                            }, $list);
    // remove all of the unfound words (where strpos returns false)
    $positions = array_filter($positions, function ($x){ return $x !== false; });

    // get the value with the key matching the lowest position.
    $key = array_search(min($positions), $positions);

    return $list[$key];
}
```

Example:

```
$str = "Hello, testing testing one test some more two";
$list = ["one","two","three"];

echo whichFirst($list, $str);
// outputs one
```